# How do you make the inside of a narrowing pipe thicker?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

[image]

I have this pipe object that I want to make the inside thicker. I tried to use the solidify modifier to make the inside thicker, but apparently it doesn't work with narrowing pipes. I want the diameter of the thickness is proportional to the pipe diameter, which narrow if the pipes narrow. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to **apply the solidify modifier** and **scale the inner edges** to the size you want.  See animation below.  Also don't forget to **apply the transform to the object when done**.

[image: img1]